# Loopback loading config files for the wrong NODE_ENV

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am very confused by this unexpected behavior from Loopback.

I have this logged from my Loopback server:

```
SFOC02Q106HG8WM:crucible-poc-discovery t_millal$ NODE_ENV=test node .
 => Loopback is loading filename =>  /Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/a/crucible-poc-discovery/server/config.local.js
 => Loopback is loading filename =>  /Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/a/crucible-poc-discovery/server/config.test.js
 => Loopback is loading filename =>  /Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/a/crucible-poc-discovery/server/datasources.local.js
 => Loopback is loading filename =>  /Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/a/crucible-poc-discovery/server/get-local-datasources.js
 => Loopback is loading filename =>  /Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/a/crucible-poc-discovery/server/datasources.test.js
```

I have specified `NODE_ENV=test`

why does Loopback still load:

`server/config.local.js` and `server/datasources.local.js`?

isn't that a bug? Is it simply because l comes before t in the alphabet?
Seems wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html) LoopBack always load the following configuration files, if they exist:

```
server/config.json.
server/config.local.json or server/config.local.js. 
server/datasources.json
server/datasources.local.json or server/datasources.local.js
server/model-config.json
server/model-config.local.json or server/model-config.local.js
server/middleware.json
server/middleware.local.json or server/middleware.local.js
server/component-config.json
```

Comment: `config.json+config.local.json` makes no sense to me because both files are static it is just redundant. `config.json+config.local.js` could be potentially convenient if you want add some logic to your configuration. Personally I never use `config.json+config.local.js` I always use `config.json+config.{_env_}.js`. Can you accept my answer?

Comment: I think local files are not meant to go into version control, rather it's for devs who want to override parameters locally, without changing the original config.

Comment: Good point I had not thought of it that way but I think we should avoid that because it can create a situation when something work locally but crash on other environments. 
"Well, it works for me." situation :)

Comment: That can happen, but it can also save you some time from installing & configuring DBs like mysql on a machine if you just want to test quickly using in-memory DB ;)

Comment: You are right in-memory DB is very useful (option with file storage also) but I think configuration like that should be stored in repo to share it with other developers